# How to check multiple occurrences of a character in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

If there is a string = '99888' it should print 'True'. How can you check pairs and threes of a character in a string

I tried using the count function but it only identifies a pair

```
string = '99888'
for c in '123456789':
    if string.count(c) == 2 and string.count(c) == 3 :
       print('True')
```

Edit:
The string is a always 5 character string and if there is a pair and three of a kind it prints True
For example '89899' and '75757' print True. '98726' prints False

Comment: Count cannot be at the same time 2 and 3.

Comment: any case where your code should print false, what would be output for  234423312356579 ( i write this number arbitarily )

Comment: @Austin unless it's a Schrodinger's character.

Comment: I **think** what you mean is, you want the string to contain exactly three of some character, and *also* contain exactly two of a *different* character. Is that correct? Or do the pairs or triplets of digits need to be next to each other; can there be more than 2 or 3 of them, etc. etc. etc. To solve a problem first requires a *precise* description of the problem.

Comment: This question is extremely unclear.  Multiple occurrences of which character?  How many? Do the occurrences need to be consecutive?

Comment: sorry I should have added this string is a 5 character string and if there is a pair and three of a kind so '88999' it prints true. '98726' prints false

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python poker", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 3):

- Use the `Counter` class from the `collections` module

```
from collections import Counter

def check(inputString):
    x = Counter(inputString)
    list_of_counts = [x[i] for i in x.elements()]

    if (2 in list_of_counts) and (3 in list_of_counts):
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False)

print(check("99888"))
print(check("999888"))
```

Comment: Suggested improvement: `list_of_counts = set(x.values())`

Comment: Replace the conditional with `return (2 in list_of_counts) and (3 in list_of_counts)`. The comparison is already a boolean.